# staggered gridview onitemclicklistener not working in fragment

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

If anybody has implemented onitemclicklistener with staggered gridview in fragment please help me ,i am stuck on that from last more than a day . i have done this with activity but i doen't know what is problem when i am using it in fragment.if anybody has any cleave than let me know my code is.

```
 mAdapter = new STGVAdapter(getActivity(),getActivity().getApplication(),Details.getarray());
        stgv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
          stgv.setOnItemClickListener(new StaggeredGridView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(StaggeredGridView parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked", 0).show();

                }
            });
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is my Gridview Cell Xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="2.5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:background="#D1D2D6"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <info.androidhive.slidingmenu.ScaleImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/img_content"
            android:background="#E7E7EF"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="news" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this one gridView Xml.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:staggered="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.bulletnoid.android.widget.StaggeredGridView.StaggeredGridView
        android:id="@+id/stgv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        staggered:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        staggered:numColumns="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: wha items does your gridview have. can you post the xml. If you have a ImageVIew or ImageButton it will take focus.

Comment: ok will update my question

Comment: try adding this `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the root element in the layout

Comment: where exactly does i write this code

Comment: at the top of the xml for the linearlayout

Comment: have tried that as well but no result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48538/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-sajad-bin-nazir)

Comment: did you try that for the root elementin grid cell xml??

Comment: Yes I have tried that with grid cell but still  no result

Comment: Hi Sajad, I am try to implement onclicklistener of staggered gridview in activity but it didn't work. How can i solve this issue in case of activity

Comment: @Sajol ,if you have more than a single click listener then u have to define click listeners in gridview adapter ,defining onclickListeners in adapter slove my problem

Comment: @sajad, Thanks for your suggestion.I fixed the problem and your assumption is correct. Basically there was a button in item of gridview. As a result click event not work. I replace that button with ImageView then click event fired nicely.

Comment: @Sajol anyways you are most welcome

Answer (score 0):

Please override onActivityCreated() method inside fragment then call the click event inside it.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    stgv.setOnItemClickListener(new StaggeredGridView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(StaggeredGridView parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item Clicked: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}
```